# Facebook SDK forPHPのクラスが読み取れない。

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

はじめまして！

現在、以下のFacebook公式サイトを参考にしながらFacebook認証の開発を進めている者です。 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

```
<?php

define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', '/fb-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/');
require __DIR__ . '/fb-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php';


// Make sure to load the Facebook SDK for PHP via composer or manually

use Facebook\FacebookSession;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('略', '略');
```

上記のようなシンプルなコードを実行した際、

> Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\FacebookSession' not found in
>   /ドメイン名/index.php on line 15

と表示されてしまいます。

ちなみに、SDKはComposerではなくGithubからダウンロードし、ルートディレクトリに配置したので、 
公式サイトにある

```
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', '/path/to/fb-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/');
require __DIR__ . '/path/to/facebook-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php';
```

の/path/to/は意図的に削除しました。

このような場合、どのような処置をとればよいでしょうか?

よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

autoload.php には次のように書かれています。

```
// base directory for the namespace prefix
$base_dir = defined('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR') ? FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR : __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/';

...

// replace the namespace prefix with the base directory, replace namespace
// separators with directory separators in the relative class name, append
// with .php
$file = $base_dir . str_replace('\\', '/', $relative_class) . '.php';

// if the file exists, require it
if (file_exists($file)) {
  require $file;
}
```

どうやら、 `FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR` はそのまま require できるパスを指定する必要があるようです。

具体的な対処としては次のどちらかになるかと思います。

- `FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR` にも `__DIR__` を付加する
- いっそ defineを 省略する→ autoload.php の場所から見た `./src/Facebook/` が使われる

ドキュメントでは require の方にだけ `__DIR__` が使われていて紛らわしいですね・・・。